# How Do I Organise This MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making my first project that uses MySQL. To do so, I need to organise the following values- Email, Subject, Questions, Answers
Here's an image showing what I had in mind
[image]

Basically, each user, identified by an email address, makes questions and answers pertaining to a given list of subjects. I am not sure how to organise it in a way that would be normalised.

Being new to MySQL, I thought it would be better to ask more experienced people first. Any ideas on how to organise this, and any tips for organising MySQL databases in general?

Comment: This is a really broad question. But consider that there will be one or more questions under each subject and each question will have one or more answers.

Comment: You need to figure out relations and multiplicity between your entities (classes). Indeed a very broad subject, read some tutorials, create database scheme with linked tables and attributes and ask a new question then.

Answer (score 0):

That image looks good to me, however...

If I read your project constraints correctly, you are limited to a discrete set of available subjects? If that is the case, a separate table of the available subjects would probably be good.

So it could be as simple as one table, but personally I might consider two (the second for subjects) just to avoid folks submitting multiple / small variations of the same subject (e.g. Math and Mathematics).

If you want to get fancy, maybe think about the implications of similar variations of essentially the same question being posted. Hypothetically, if the database were for an FAQ application, when someone is drafting a question that is very similar to another question that has already received a reply, you may want to redirect that person to that question before they submit their new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way in MySQL I can think of.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_user`;
CREATE TABLE `_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `questions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `questions` (
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `question` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `subject_id` (`subject_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `answers`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answers`(
  `answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question_id` int(11)  DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11)   DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`answer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subjects`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;
```

The query should look something like this--

```
 $query = "SELECT 
questions.question,
answers.answer,
subjects.subject,
_user.email_address
FROM questions
INNER JOIN answers
ON answers.question_id = questions.question_id
LEFT JOIN subjects
ON subjects.subject_id = questions.subject_id
LEFT JOIN _user
ON _user.user_id = questions.user_id
";
```

Comment: I place the "DROP TABLE" before the table creation so I  can quickly overwrite the database while developing.  It's better to become familiar with 'phpmyadmin'.

Comment: thanks! I tried out the code and it worked well. However, it would really help to know in what way would you convert the image in the question to code (using exactly the values given) https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa1Xe.png.

Comment: Oops!   I didn't see the image.  Sry.  Add another table to sort the questions into categories and add a Key value to the question, puttin it into a category.

Comment: Better explanation. Add another "categories' table to sort  the question, linking it to a category.  When you query the tables, try to use a single call with JOINS, --create a multi-dimensional array from the query, then fill your table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the preferred design for you case:

[image]

Each user can has many `question`s on every `subject`,

And each `Subject` can has many `user`s' `questions`

*In each table you can add the remaining data you want*